# ADB can't recognize my Android phone, but Windows 7 does

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, drivers, android

I'm trying to install a simple .apk, from my Asys U46E running Windows 7, onto my LG Optimus S running Android 2.3.3.

If I have USB debugging off on the phone, then the laptop recognizes it and can interact with its SD card's folders; I dropped the apk into the SD card's Downloads folder.

But regardless of whether USB debugging is on or off, adb won't recognize the phone: the command "adb devices" returns an empty list. adb kill-server doesn't fix it.

I've installed the generically-named Android USB Driver, and apparently Windows 7 was able to install a working driver for my phone of some sort. What's left to do?

Comment: What does your `Device Manager` say? (Right click My Computer, Select Manage, Select Device Manager). See if there's a yellow caution triangle on it. Just because you can use the file system doesn't mean the adb interface should work. How did you install the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Your phone manufacer might have different adb driver, google  your phone model and adb driver. For an example, my MOTO G was detected by computer, but adb didn't work. After installing adb driver still nothing, but after installing Motorola device mananger everything worked. So just google for a (adb) driver for your phone.